# PHP:Postgresql issue on Windows

Tags: php, windows-7, xampp, postgresql-9.1, phppgadmin

"Your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL. You need to recompile PHP using the --with-pgsql configure option."

I am facing this issue on windows when I try to access PhpPgAdmin. My postgresql version is 9.1 and PHP is installed in WAMP stack. I tried enabling the php_pgsql extension but didn't work. Plz help on what needs to be done to make it work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As it says, your installation doesn't support PGSQL, because XAMPP is laid down to be used with mySql. [This](http://phpwebscript.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-install-xampp-in-support-with.html) might help you though,

Comment: sorry i am using wamp. that was a typo